# Electric cooktop for sous vide-level precision?

Tags: equipment, temperature, sous-vide

Yes, I know, but bear with me here.

I've been thinking about getting an electric cooktop, and reading about them online a lot of people seem to mention that on some of the low settings, their cooktop will keep water at a constant boiling/simmering temperatures, like, say, 90 C (194 F)

In order for that to happen, it must mean that the heating element itself is only heating up to that temperature, high? And thus of course the temperature cannot get higher than the hot plate itself.

By that logic, if an electric cooktop happened to have a setting that would leave it at around 74 C (165 F), does that mean I could use it to cook some chicken breast precisely to its safe internal temperature?

Would be like a sous vide - no risk of over- or undercooking it! Right? Or am I missing something?

EDIT: For further clarification, when I say electric, I mean traditional ones with a solid plate burner. Sorry!

---

EDIT 2: Okay, so not sous vide-level precision. I've learned a lot from your wonderful answers, and my new plan is to lower my standards and attempt the following:

1. Putting a pot of water with a lid on the electric coil cooker (so it's an enclosed space filled with a great thermal conductor)
2. Cycle the device on and off figure out a rate for, erhm... manual time modulation that would keep the coil at X+Y Celsius (where X is the temp I want and Y is however many more degrees it needs to be to compensate for heat loss, which I would need to figure out for that setup as well)
3. Turn it on and off again at regular intervals according to the rate I found (yeah impractical but I could get a smart outlet to do it for me if it works!)

Maybe I could get a large pot (more thermal mass, less temp variation) and exclusively use it for this (more consistent setup, less temp variation), and figure out a reliable duty cycle that keeps it at a given temperature for three different quantities of water (such as a third, two thirds, and nearly full capacity).

Hopefully I can end up with water consistently at maybe +-4 C of a target temperature, and finally achieve hands-off, dummy-proof cooking! (useful since I can be a bit of a dummy sometimes). If you're wondering why I don't get a circulator, I've made a comment down below to clarify.

Comment: What kind of "electric cooktop" ? induction ? coils or ceramic ?

Comment: I meant a traditional one with a coil burner. My bad! I edited the question to add it, is that all right? It's my first post here so I'm still getting the hang of it ^^'

Comment: I don't know of any coil-based electric that has that kind of precision.  Induction burners, sure, but coils?  No.

Comment: I used to have a halogen that had one specifically low simmer ring. It would go low enough to slow-cook, 8-12 hrs for a chilli etc. I never checked its actual temperature, but it was below 'bubbling'. I've never known an old-style coil ring that could do it.

Comment: For those wondering why I don't just get an immersion circulator for this:

1. I live in a developing country where they are rare and cost at least $250, and $250 is significally more money when adjusted for the living standards here. 

This is the same reason why it's not super easy for me to find or rig a temperature controller to the cooktop.

2. I don't really want to sous vide, I just want some degree of control over temperature when cooking stuff in water the normal way. I don't think the circulator would react well to me placing food straight in the water, bagless.

Comment: Whoops. I'm not a native English speaker and got my terms confused: I meant a solid plate electric cooktop, not coil. I've updated the question, although I don't think it's super relevant for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: "Dutch oven", "slow cooker", even "bain marie". You're somewhat limited to cooking the types of food that are good for cooking that way, but if you're OK with a more limited number of dishes they are pretty fool-proof.

Comment: The solid plate type makes it far harder, because the plate itself ha a lot of thermal mass (thermal mass of liquid that you're cooking in is good, at the heat source it's bad).  Your best bet is going to be a large pot and a thermometer: when the temperature rises towards what you want, turn the heat off, when it falls towards what you want, turn it on again.  The various settings on the dial of the hotplate can be used to speed up or slow down this feedback loop, and if you cook similar quantities regularly you'll get a  feel for it. Lowest power may even be just cool enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely not, this cannot be built. There is a reason sous vide is called sous vide and not sous PID. Cooktops are, by design, a device that emits a constant amount of energy (oversimplified) into the surrounding space, which is the opposite of what you need for keeping a constant internal temperature in a chicken breast.

If you would build a cooktop with a heat element that would stay constantly at 74 C, then put a pot of water on it, the pot would constantly sit at (74 - X) C due to thermal loss. X will vary for each combination of pot and water volume you use. And the water is a special case which you can keep at a constant temperature that way, not a chicken breast. So even if somebody were to put in the expense and effort to build such a heater (and nobody does, both resistive and induction heaters are time modulated), you still wouldn't get what you want.

If you do want your food to stay at a constant temperature, you first have to put it in an enclosed space, then heat the fluid in that space to a constant temperature. The traditional way to do it is with an oven. Keeping an oven at constant 74 C is possible, but if you put a naked chicken breast in it, it would take too many hours to get to be 74 C internally. So the next logical step is to surround it not with a great insulator like air, but a great thermal conductor like water - and then you have built the simplest device suitable for the task, which is a sous vide.

---

For completeness, there are cooktops with a probe that goes into the food, although they are niche and expensive, or you could rig one yourself. They would work for the pot of water, but for frying a chicken breast, the element will be working just like an old-fashioned heat element and heat to much over 74 C, until the breast itself reaches 74 C, at which time the cook would remove the breast instead of letting it sit there, so the controller would never even get a chance to start working and the situation is equivalent to sticking an external probe in the breast.

---

Update in response to your Edit 2:

If all you want is to keep a pot of soup/stew in a not-too-precise temperature range, all you need is to take a standard cooktop and put the dial at the proper setting, "proper" being something you learn by trial-and-error for your combination of stovetop, pot and batch size, fine adjusted by observation during cooking. You may have to readjust a bit over time, but only rarely. This is not some new method though, this is the way everybody cooks on stovetop. I don't see why you would complicate things by trying to overcompensate (and introduce new errors) by manually turning on and off on a preset schedule. That would mean both more work and worse results than the normal way of cooking.

Comment: I suspect the ones with a probe to go in a pot of liquid just turn the element on and off, deficit could be copied. A similar method to the slow cooker sous vide probe/controller could be used with a basic plug-in coil, halogen, or induction ring, (i.e. one without much thermal mass) but it wouldn't be very good even under a pan of water. A lab hotplate using this method and a small container of water is only slightly less precise than a sous vide circulator.

Comment: @ChrisH sure, if you want to heat soup and have a plate that agrees with being controlled, that would work well (portable induction units usually don't turn on after capping and then resupplying the electricity). Or if you want the chicken breast sous vide, the same principle but with an immersion heater and pump works. Although these days, the sticks are cheaper than buying heater, controller and pump. But of course it works, it is the same setup as inside a stick, just not in one neat package.

Comment: I reckon it would have to be a cheap hotplate, to not be too clever, but mine has too much thermal mass (the resistive type that doesn't glow)

Comment: @ChrisH on a side note, do you ever use the chatrooms? I would have a few questions unsuitable for the main page, and your experience with both lab equipment and cooking would be very valuable, so I would want to ask you about them.

Comment: Very rarely - my time zone and schedule don't seem to align with many people's so the discussion has normally moved on by the time I get back to it. I'm not sure if @ mentions work fully there, but if they do, I'm happy to get involved

Comment: @ChrisH I am in Europe, so that should be only 1 hour time difference, I believe. (So is Stephie, who is also active in our chat) And @ mentions do work in chat, at least for several days after a user has been in the room. I couldn't @ you there before you have joined though. (OK, I personally could have, with my mod superpowers, but I shouldn't be using them for a mere desire for personal chat). So if you would like to join us in the Frying pan, you are welcome!

Comment: Thank you both for all your help! @ChrisH I can see how the thermal mass would be a problem for the probe setup, but this makes me think it could be beneficial if I were to control temperature by cycling the device on and off! My aim is to keep the burner at a somewhat constant temperature, and if I were to do that by doing some time modulation manually, too little would make it fluctuate wildly, while too much would even it out and allow me to keep constant without too short a cycle! Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks a lot for the answer! Pardon my stubbornness, but by your description I'm thinking I could get a decent result with some compromise. I've lowered my standards a bit and described a new method in the question. Do you think that would be more attainable? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

That's not how it works. Most electrics are induction these days, which heat through magnetic fields. They impart energy to the metal of the pan, heating the metal directly. Traditional heating coils or halogens create actual heat, the temperature that food or water reaches in any electric system including induction varies significantly on the:

- Size and shape of the pan
- Pan material
- How much food or water is in the pan

So there's no 74°C setting, you select an amount of power to impart on the pan. Also, cooktops are missing some things sous vide systems have:

1. A temperature sensor in the water to keep it exactly where it needs to be. Without a sensor in the water there's no data on how much heat is needed and you'll be over or under temperature. When you put food into a sous vide bath the temperature is going to drop, the energy level needs to increase to compensate, then drop again
2. A pump to circulate the water around to keep heat even: without the pump you'll get hot and cold spots which could lead to your food being unsafe

That's not to say you can't get close, once you get to know your cooktop and your pans you'll be able to set it up so that you get a relatively consistent temperature and be able to leave it for awhile, but it won't be that 'set it and forget it' sous vide precision.

Comment: That quite surprised me [not that I've been looking for a new hob recently & I prefer gas anyway] but a quick scroll through one of the UK's largest box-shifters does show maybe 60-70% induction, the others ceramic. Out of hundreds, only 4 [all the same make] were old-style solid plate, none were 'coiled' plate. *Edit:* I found the stats in the sidebar - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQB4Z.png [I hadn't been through every single page]

Comment: Induction is hugely popular for some reason @Tetsujin, personally I'm not a fan. Pans skate around, you can't use many pans and the electronics are fragile, pull a hot pan over the controls and they're fried! I'm gas all the way. That sounds wrong.

Comment: I grew up with solid plate at my parents'. When I bought my first home I got a halogen, which I did quite like. Since then I've always had gas & wouldn't dream of going back to electric. Especially the new touch systems. Horrible to work with, can't tell if a ring is on or off… not for me at all.

Comment: I agree @Tetsujin, induction is like cooking on an ipad.

Comment: That did actually make me laugh out loud ;))

Comment: @GdD Big reason induction is popular: Not piping explosive, noxious gases into your home and burning them, creating other noxious gases and the possibility of an explosion that will level my house and kill me and my neighbors.

Comment: My gas hob has automatic cut-off valves if a flame goes out @DanC. Problem solved.

Comment: @GdD Even when it's working correctly, burning gas in your cooktop creates air pollution in your house. And your cut-off won't help when someone doing work in the street accidentally cuts a gas line that later explodes, something which happened in my neighborhood not long ago, destroying three houses and killing two people.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @DanC!

Comment: @GdD First, there are many countries where houses are not supplied with gas lines, and there are also not many indoors-intended cooktops. People sometimes use camping stoves inside, which is dangerous for its own reasons. And I hate the ipad feeling too, but it is not related to gas, nowadays all electric technologies beside metal-covered resistives come with these controls. I must say I love the ceran concept, so easy to push pots around, I just wish the controls were separate and more haptic.

Comment: Yeah, you both touch on the reasons why I'm going for electric, specifically solid plate. Not super comfortable with gas, and I imagine cooking on a glass surface to be unpleasant. I generally avoid glass in my life since it's heavy and breaks. Solid plate is the best of both worlds if you don't hate its slow response times, which I'm thinking won't be that big of a problem for my application.